# Using sprinft() with nested variables - how?

Tags: php, string, function, printf

I'm trying to translate WordPress website using `gettext()`. Documentation says this:

> Use format strings instead of string concatenation —`sprintf(__('Replace %1$s with %2$s'), $a, $b);` is always better than `__('Replace').$a.__(' with ').$b;`

I want to follow this advice but here comes the problem:

```
<?php _e('You must be', 'textdomain'); ?> 
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php _e('logged in', 'textdomain'); ?>
    </a> 
<?php _e('to post a comment.', 'textdomain'); ?>
```

This would either require some nested `sprintf()` or I would have to leave it like that - split into 3 strings (or at least 2). I'm not PHP expert, so if someone knows a way to get around this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
sprintf(_e('You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.', 'textdomain'), bloginfo('url') . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . the_permalink());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But `<a href=""` part and `</a>` shouldn't go to string - that's the problem. Functions such as `__()` and `_e()` should contain only English string ready for translation.

Comment: Anyway, it seems like it's not possible to create good looking nested function, so I think I will go with your example. It will always contain either `</a>` or multiple `%s` which is the same level of string complexity. Thanks again!

Comment: In this way, sentence is readable. An example from wordpress.  `wp_die( sprintf(__('An error occurred adding you to this site. Back to the <a href="%s">homepage</a>.'), site_url() ) );`

Comment: I agree. That's what I'm going to use.